# How do I embolden, underline (inline style as in HTML) individual texts in a dictionary for display in Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on an English to my native language dictionary with python dictionary. While working with key value pair, I want to be able to style certain individual words in the values, embolden, underline, etc. For example, the words capitalized in the first value. I tried to add the ANSI escape sequence before "\033[1m" before and "\033[0m" after the targeted text it still wouldn't work; rather the sequence code was printed out.
How do I do this? Thanks. Below is an excerpt of the dictionary:

```
#Dictionary
exlist={
    "drum":"\033[1m DRUM \033[0m: (with skin) ŋgɔ̀m; (long, single-headed, skin-covered) ɨbûm ŋgɔ̀m; (with one end) ŋgɔ̀m ə̀tu", 
    "bag":"BAG: (n) ə̀bàmɨ̀ pl. ɨ̀bàmɨ̀; (assp) (fibre bag) ə̀bàmɨ̀ tɨswé; (a type of bag made of animal skin) ndoŋ",
    "ant":"ANT: ɨgwírɨ́ (pl. əgwirɨ); (has a big croup) ɨgwírɨ́ ndiŋ; (ant species, very small, attack and destroy white ants)"
}
```

Comment: Hint: "`Text` widgets allow you to define names for regions of the text called _tags_. You can change the appearance of a tagged region, changing its font, foreground and background colors, and other options."" Here's some documentation on [`Text` widget tags](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-tag.html).

Comment: I've modified my question to make it explicit. What I'm asking is, is there an inline styling in python, as in HTML?

Comment: No, tkinter does not support an inline styling system like that. There's support for text fonts that can be applied to some or all of the text in some widgets in various ways, depending on what type of widget is involved. `Text` widgets are the most versatile in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to bold/underline/italic text in Tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

thing1 = Label(root, text='Bolded', font=("Roberto 50 bold"))
thing1.pack()

thing2 = Label(root, text='Underlined', font=("Roberto 50 underline"))
thing2.pack()

thing3 = Label(root, text='Italiced', font=("Roberto 50 italic"))
thing3.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: This will style everything. Is there an inline styling in python as it is in HTML? I want to style individual words. I've modified my question above.